# What are the security implications of doing “chmod a+rx ~/Documents”?

Tags: macos, security, unix, osx-lion

In order to get the Apache in Mac OS X Lion to work with symlinks, I had to follow the instructions on this page: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1771399?threadID=1771399

One of the things I have to do is execute

```
chmod a+rx ~/Documents
```

The resulting permission of my Documents folder looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 27 enchilada  staff    918 13 apr 11:36 Documents
```

This works fine. Now Apache can properly follow symlinks. However, my question is: Does this pose any serious security hazards that I should know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will allow any user account on your system to enter the given directory and list its contents, including other users of your Mac, including the Guest account, if activated.

It will not affect your files through data modification or destruction, and by itself does not give permissions to read the files. But since default file access permissions allow reading everything and entering directories for all users unless you specifically prevent it, they can  be read and copied. (That's also good to know for new top-level directories in `~`, they're accessible to everyone on OS X by default!)

Some programs use special unprivileged user accounts as a security measure. By doing this, you'll probably circumvent the protection inherent in this.

Unless you hit buggy software (which for desktop and laptop computers is far more likely to be user software running under your user) or share much of your home directory or file system through other means, it won't be a real issue.

---

Regarding those instructions, they're probably too permissive.

It should suffice to make all directories on the path to e.g. `~/Documents/test` executable. That's why you can *enter* other users' home directories; otherwise you wouldn't get to `~/Sites` or `~/Public`.

Just run `chmod a+x ~/Documents` (any user can enter the directory) and `chmod a+rx ~/Documents/test` (other all users can enter and read the actual directory you want to make accessible via Apache) and see whether that works.

Comment: Actually, changing user or group to the one used by the Apache server process and assigning appropriate rights would be consequent. Also, IIRC, `a+rx` on a directory should give any user the right to change into *that* directory *(x)*, not the subdirs, and to read the list of files *(r)* of that directory, not the contents of the contained files. (That the files might have read rights set and reading them might(?) be prevented by not setting x on the dir is another story)

Comment: @zpea Right, I saw a `-R` where none was. Will adjust my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @zpea and OP: Is there no way to make (using the example of the OP) `~/Documents` a+x and `~/Documents/test` a+rx *only for the Apache user*, as opposed to *every user* on the system? How would I go about doing that? I don’t want normal users, including the Guest user, to be able to browse into my Documents folder.

Comment: @Enchilada Try using ACLs. Run `sudo -u _www ls /Users/username/Documents` to see an error message, since `_www` is not allowed to list `/Users/username/Documents`. Run `chmod +a "_www allow list,search" ~/Documents` and try again. Repeat as needed. `ls -e` will show these ACLs, `man chmod` contains a more thorough explanation and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It also looks like one of the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/q/2001881/288444 addresses this same thing. Thanks again.

Comment: @Enchilada Those posts make the `_www` internal system account the owner of the files and folders in question. You wouldn't be able to access or write to your Documents folder anymore if you did that. My advice keeps you the owner, and just adds an extra rule for `_www` to the folder. Verify using `ls -l ~/Documents`.

Comment: @DanielBeck Well, what I did was create a `~/webroot` folder, where all of my website stuff will go, for example, my site `~/webroot/foo.com` will be there. Within that, we have something like `~/webroot/foo.com/private` and `~/webroot/foo.com/public`. I have a symlink inside `~/Sites` to `~/webroot/foo.com/public`. To give Apache access, I just changed the **group** of `~/webroot` to `_www` and gave this group read and execute privileges. It seems to be working fine. I’m still the owner of the folder, so I can access it. Does this sound good?

Comment: @DanielBeck Also, a final question: How come I could change the group to `_www`, leaving the user as it is? I thought a file/dir had to have its user/group set such that the user is actually a part of group. I guess not...

Comment: @Enchilada It'll just prevent access from other users on the machine that would have been e.g. in `staff` group. Owner and group are independent. The best match applies. You can even prohibit the "owning" group's access but allow for "others", but that's only useful if group membership can only reassigned by administrators.